# Horizontal scroll bars not appearing in SSRS 2012 report

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have built a report that when testing in the Report builder works perfectly and scroll bars are displayed along the bpttpm of the screen.  However, when viewed in browser the report does not display the scroll bar and you have to navigate to the hidden fields using the arrow keys.  How do I get the horizontal scroll bar to appear?  the verical scroll bar works perfectly.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Can you show the design of the report? What browser are you using?

Comment: Difficult to show it since it contains a lot of confidential informaiton (built for a radiologists billing system).  I've tested in Chrome, edge and IE- all have the same issue